# DVC Push KeyError fileSize

Tags: dvc

I've added a large list of CSV files to my dvc repository but when I try to do DVC push it complains with

```
ERROR: unexpected error - KeyError('fileSize')
```

**Edit**
So searching around it seem that it might help to include the verbose log with regards to the error.

```
T11:27:08~/documents/*****/data$ dvc push -v
2022-02-01 11:32:13,186 DEBUG: Adding '/home/jhylands/Documents/*****/.dvc/config.local' to gitignore file.
2022-02-01 11:32:13,199 DEBUG: Adding '/home/jhylands/Documents/*****/.dvc/tmp' to gitignore file.
2022-02-01 11:32:13,200 DEBUG: Adding '/home/jhylands/Documents/*****/.dvc/cache' to gitignore file.
2022-02-01 11:32:14,102 DEBUG: Preparing to transfer data from '/home/jhylands/Documents/*****/.dvc/cache' to '*********'
2022-02-01 11:32:14,102 DEBUG: Preparing to collect status from '********'
2022-02-01 11:32:14,103 DEBUG: Collecting status from '*******'
2022-02-01 11:32:14,439 DEBUG: GDrive remote auth with config '{'client_config_backend': 'settings', 'client_config_file': 'client_secrets.json', 'save_credentials': True, 'oauth_scope': ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata'], 'save_credentials_backend': 'file', 'save_credentials_file': '/home/jhylands/Documents/*****/.dvc/tmp/gdrive-user-credentials.json', 'get_refresh_token': True, 'client_config': {'client_id': '*****.apps.googleusercontent.com', 'client_secret': '****************', 'auth_uri': 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth', 'token_uri': 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token', 'revoke_uri': 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke', 'redirect_uri': ''}}'.
2022-02-01 11:32:14,994 DEBUG: Estimated remote size: 256 files
2022-02-01 11:32:14,995 DEBUG: Querying '316' hashes via traverse
2022-02-01 11:32:15,325 ERROR: unexpected error - KeyError('fileSize')
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jhylands/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrive2/files.py", line 226, in __getitem__
    return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
KeyError: 'fileSize'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jhylands/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dvc/main.py", line 55, in main
    ret = cmd.do_run()
  File "/home/jhylands/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dvc/command/base.py", line 45, in do_run
    return self.run()
  File "/home/jhylands/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dvc/command/data_sync.py", line 57, in run
    processed_files_count = self.repo.push(
  File "/home/jhylands/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dvc/repo/__init__.py", line 49, in wrapper
    return f(repo, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jhylands/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dvc/repo/push.py", line 56, in push
    pushed += self.cloud.push(
  File "/home/jhylands/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dvc/data_cloud.py", line 85, in push
    return transfer(
  File "/home/jhylands/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dvc/objects/transfer.py", line 153, in transfer
    status = compare_status(src, dest, obj_ids, check_deleted=False, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jhylands/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dvc/objects/status.py", line 158, in compare_status
    dest_exists, dest_missing = status(
  File "/home/jhylands/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dvc/objects/status.py", line 131, in status
    exists.update(odb.hashes_exist(hashes, name=odb.fs_path, **kwargs))
  File "/home/jhylands/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dvc/objects/db/base.py", line 499, in hashes_exist
    remote_hashes = set(
  File "/home/jhylands/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dvc/objects/db/base.py", line 334, in _list_hashes_traverse
    yield from itertools.chain.from_iterable(in_remote)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 611, in result_iterator
    yield fs.pop().result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 439, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 388, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/jhylands/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dvc/objects/db/base.py", line 324, in list_with_update
    return list(
  File "/home/jhylands/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dvc/objects/db/base.py", line 215, in _list_hashes
    for path in self._list_paths(prefix, progress_callback):
  File "/home/jhylands/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dvc/objects/db/base.py", line 195, in _list_paths
    for file_info in self.fs.find(fs_path, prefix=prefix):
  File "/home/jhylands/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dvc/fs/fsspec_wrapper.py", line 107, in find
    yield from self.fs.find(path)
  File "/home/jhylands/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrive2/fs/spec.py", line 323, in find
    "size": int(item["fileSize"]),
  File "/home/jhylands/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrive2/files.py", line 229, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(e)
KeyError: KeyError('fileSize')
```

Comment: Although I still don't fully understand the issue it seems that trying to setup a new remote helped to fix the issue. I presume that the local understanding of the remote and remote's true self didn't align

Comment: Hi! Could you please clarify on this "I presume that the local understanding of the remote and remote's true self didn't align"? I'm looking into the issue, can't say from the brief look. What directory/folder were you using for the remote storage, did it have any files before?

Comment: I had set up the remote to a google drive folder. This had 2 hashed folders in it (two folders with 2 digit numbers).  Changing the remove to a brand new folder in google drive allowed me to push with no issue. I did also try deleting the existing files in the original google drive folder but that didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: I don't recal well because I wasn't expecting it to be an issue but is there a problem trying to push an empty folder? I wonder if pushing the empty folder corrupted the original folder in the google drive (so that remote was corrupted) and then when try to push again to the original google drive that corruption caused failures?

Comment: I had assumed that because changing to a brand new remote solved the issue that the source of the issue might be in the stage when DVC was trying to work out if it was ahead or behind the remote. I don't have an understanding of the underlying implementation so that is just uniformed conjecture.